# Printing HTML with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

Here is a problem I am having when using Node.js:

This is my code in index.js:

```
.....
app.get('/xyz', function(request, response) {
  fs = require('fs');
  fs.readFile('views/pages/xyz.ejs', 'utf8', function (err,data) {

  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }

  response.render('pages/xyz', {result:data});
  });
});
.....
```

Here is xyz.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

<% displayStr=result.replace("\n", "<br/>"); %>
<%= displayStr %>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is what I get in my browser, when I point it to top/yxz :

```
<!DOCTYPE html><br/><html> <head> </head> <body> <div class="container"> <% displayStr=result.replace("\n", "<br/>"); %> <%= displayStr %> </div> </body> </html>
```

Even though there are line break tags (`<br/>`), I get a one long line text display instead of an HTML display.
I tried various things I could find, but nothing worked.

What should I do to obtain a normal display line by line?

Comment: @mplungian Thanks for the edit. For some reason I couldn't get it right.

Comment: Can `xyz.ejs` be changed itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

index.js:

```
...
response.render('pages/xyz', {result:'<xmp>'+data+'</xmp>'});
...
```

xyz.ejs: (Unescaped buffering with **<%-** code %>)

```
...
<% displayStr=result.replace("\n", "<br/>"); %>
<%- displayStr %>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to read manually the file.

Can you try:

```
app.get('/xyz', function(request, response) {
  response.render('pages/xyz');
});
```

Of course, before you should:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Comment: No, no. I have to. My purpose here is to display its contents. Otherwise it is working with no problems. Thanks anyway.